# How to change JSON key name using Jackson

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jackson

I am new to use Jackson API. I have created a spring boot application and tried to change the keys of a JSON string.

```
package com.poc.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Employee {
    @JsonProperty("employeeId")
    private Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("employeeName")
    private String name;
}
--------------------------------
package com.poc.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.poc.entity.Employee;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/emp")
public class EmployeeController {
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> get() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{ \"employeeId\" : \"123\", \"employeeName\" : \"John Smith\" }";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Employee employee = mapper.readValue(json, Employee.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Expected result: {"id":123,"name":"John Smith"}

But it is giving: {"employeeId":123,"employeeName":"John Smith"}

Please help me to fix it. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By appling the annotation to a property you apply it to both the setter (used for deserialization - reading from json to java object) and getter (used for serialization - converting java object to json).

You need to use `@JsonProperty` on getter and setter and define values accordingly on each:

```java
public class Employee {
   private Integer id;

   @JsonProperty("employeeName")
   private String name;
    
   @JsonProperty("id")
   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }
   
   @JsonProperty("employeeId")
   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Works as expected. But i am using Lombok in my project. So, there are no setters and getters. Is there any way to do it without generating getters & setters.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when using Lombok, the @Getter and @Setter or @Data annotations will create the getter and setter methods during compile-time, and those methods will have standard naming conventions based on the field name. If you want to use different @JsonProperty annotations for the getter and setter of the same field (which is unusual), you can't use Lombok's annotations for that field. You have to manually define the getter and setter.